# Issue with Google apps script attempting to create

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script that scans through the last 24 hours of recieved e-mails, identifies e-mails that contain 'From: 06/08/2023' with the date being today's date, from a certain e-mail address. I then want it to send another e-mail to a separate e-mail address to serve as a notification. Here is where I am currently:

```
function formatDate(date) {
  if (!date) {
    return ''; // Return an empty string if date is undefined or null
  }

  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}

function checkRecentEmails() {
  var cutoffDate = new Date();
  cutoffDate.setDate(cutoffDate.getDate() - 1); // Subtract 1 day from the current date

  var searchQuery = "is:unread after:" + Utilities.formatDate(cutoffDate, "GMT", "yyyy/MM/dd");
  var threads = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {q: searchQuery}).messages;

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var message = Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', threads[i].id);
    var fromAddress = message.payload.headers.find(function(header) {
      return header.name === 'From';
    }).value;
    var subject = message.payload.headers.find(function(header) {
      return header.name === 'Subject';
    }).value;
    var body = message.snippet;

    var today = new Date();
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");

    if (fromAddress === 'no-reply@ezrentout.com' && body.indexOf(formattedDate) !== -1) {
      // Perform the desired action for matching emails
      // For example, send an email notification
      var recipient = 'carelinenservice@gmail.com';
      var emailSubject = 'New email received from ' + fromAddress + ': ' + subject;
      var emailBody = 'From: ' + fromAddress + '\n\n' +
        'Subject: ' + subject + '\n\n' +
        'Body: ' + body;

      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, emailSubject, emailBody);
    }
  }
}
```

Most was generated via ChatGPT of course and I am quite new to this type of stuff so I'm assuming there is a really basic error I'm missing. I have the Gmail API enabled in the services portion on the left. Below is a sample e-mail that I currently have in my Inbox, yet this script does not generate the trigger e-mail:

Sample no-reply@ezrentout.com Unsubscribe
11:27 AM (43 minutes ago)
to me

Hello Keith Logan,

You have booked Order# 10545 for Keith Logan. The booking duration is from 06/08/2023 04:00 PM to 06/15/2023 10:00 AM.

See full details from your EZRentOut account.

From: 06/08/2023 04:00 PM
To: 06/15/2023 10:00 AM
Duration: 6 days 18 hours 1 minute

Items in the order:
ID  Name    Duration/Quantity
Asset Stock # 25    Bath Towels 1 Weeks/Qty: 1
Asset Stock # 23    Washcloth   1 Weeks/Qty: 1

From all that I can see this e-mail should be caught by the search, and then the notification e-mail should be generated. Thank you for any help you can provide!